# problem installing mariadb using mysql_secure_installation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, installation, errors, root

I started secure install of MySQL with `sudo mysql_secure_installation` command, and I got that message:

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

```
Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Despite the name, `mysql_secure_installation` is not for *installing* MariaDB; it used to secure an *existing* installation of MariaDB.

You should use some other method to install MariaDB (e.g. using your favourite package manager), then run `mysql_secure_installation`.